# Problem with getting predecessor in BinarySearchTree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

This is my getBefore method

```
 public Node getBefore() {
    return getBeforeHelper(root, this.data);
}

public Node getBeforeHelper(Node node, K key) {
    Node current = null;
    if(node != null) {
        if(node.data == key) {
            if(node.left != null) {
                current = node.left;
                while(current.right != null) {
                    current = current.right;
                }
                System.out.println(current.get());
                return current;
            }
        }
        else if(lessThan.test(key, node.data)) {
            return getBeforeHelper(node.left, key);
        }
        else if(lessThan.test(node.data, key)) {
            return getBeforeHelper(node.right, key);
        }
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
    return current;
}
```

and this is the Junit test that it is failing to pass

```
@Test
public void beforeBST() {
BinarySearchTree<Integer> bst = new BinarySearchTree<>((Integer x, Integer y) -> x < y);
assertTrue(bst.isEmpty());
int[] a = new int[] { 12, 4, 18, 5, 11, 8, 15, 9, 17, 20, 3, 13, 19, 2, 14, 7, 6, 10, 1, 16 };
int n = a.length;
for (Integer key : a) 
  bst.insert(key);
assertNull(bst.search(1).getBefore());
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    System.out.println(bst.search(2).getBefore());
    assertTrue(i - 1 == bst.search(i).getBefore().get());
}
```

}

It gets to the assertTrue in the last for loop and then fails with a null pointer exception. Why is it throwing a null pointer?

Answer (score 0):

When the method getBeforeHelper finds the element with your key, it tries to get the left element. That doesn't work if your left element does not exist. In this case getBeforeHelper returns 'current' which is null.
In this case you call get() to this null-element and get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you end up in a case where:

```
//                             this yields null
//                               v          v
assertTrue(i - 1 == bst.search(i).getBefore().get());
//                                           ^    ^
//                   attempt to access a method belonging to a null reference
```

---

Consider the case where, in `getBeforeHelper`, you have:

- `node != null` (always `true` in the test that's causing trouble)
- `node.data == key` (`true` when you've reached the `Node` you were looking for)
- `node.left == null` (just think about it: when does that happen?)

In that case, you end up virtually with the following body for the `getBeforeHelper` method (by discarding all the `else` blocks where you did pass the `if` test and discarding all the contents of the `if` block whose test failed):

```
public Node getBeforeHelper(Node node, K key) {
    Node current = null;
    if(node != null) { // true
        if(node.data == key) { // true
            if(node.left != null) { // false
            }
        }
    }

    return current;
}
```

Well, right there, you're returning `null`.
And later down the line, attempting to evaluate `null.get()` in your assertion.

All that's left for you to do is understand **when** exactly this occurs and find another non-failing way to deal with it! I've dropped a little hint above, but since it really seems like you're learning, I will let you figure out the fine details `:)`.

Comment: Ok so when I return the current at the very end that should be returning another Node?

Comment: If the left node equals null then you should return another node.  
(Everytime the left node does not exist, one of the parent nodes is the one you are searching for.)  
Suggestion for a solution:  
If you do not find a left node, you need to check the parent node of the node with your key. If this parent node is an upper right one you check the parent of this parent node and so on.  
Otherwise if your parent node is an upper left one, this node is the one you are searching for.  
(Sorry for my bad english)